# Create triangle with numbers in this pattern using for loops in java?

Tags: java

The output needs to look like

> ```
> 1 
> 2 5 
> 3 6 8 
> 4 7 9 10
> ```

It has to be created using for loops. So far I have ( this is one method of a larger program).

```
public static void triangle3( int n ) {
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        int spaceCount = n - i;
        int k = n;
        for( int j=1; j<spaceCount; j++)
            System.out.print("   ");
        for( int j=1; j<=i+1; j++ )
            System.out.printf("%3d", j );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: i dont know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Oh man. Check the formatting of your question. Didnt you see that the question does not show a triangle in the first place?!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TriangleOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        triangle3(4);
    }

    public static void triangle3( int n ) {
        int[][] arr = new int[n][n];

        int count = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = j; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i][j] = count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if (j > 0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Gives

```
1
2 5
3 6 8
4 7 9 10
```